# Is it safe to store user's data using react redux persist

Tags: reactjs, redux, persist

I was using react redux but, when I refresh the data was deleted, so now I am planning to use react redux persist to keep data stored.

Comment: What's the definition of "safe" here?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use backend instead of handling this thing using react, what I am trying to say is make one api in backend which will provide you the data of the user which is currently logged in using the auth token which you will pass in the header and call that API first whenever the page is refreshed and directly store the response into your redux this way even on refresh your data will not vanish away.

Comment: Thank you for your response, is it possible to provide an example or a project example

Comment: Currently I am not having any git repo but I will post an update to you shortly.